# How would you prompt user for a keyword to search then perform the search using VBScript?

Tags: vbscript

I would like to prompt the user, maybe via an InputBox, to input a keyword.  Once they type in, say creek, then hit enter, I would then like to run something like:

```
dir *creek* /s
```

And '/s' may not exactly be the best as I would like to return to the user the file name(s) only while /s returns more than just the file names.

I found [Vbscripting to search for file via user input, calling functions to ask a series of questions to do tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26154660/vbscripting-to-search-for-file-via-user-input-calling-functions-to-ask-a-series) to work well but I am trying to make it more user friendly, especially give it the ability to use a wildcard.

Comment: I think this is too broad for SO. What part of this are you having problems with? Getting user input in a vbscript? Searching files on a computer with a wildcard? Displaying results from an array of file names that were found with a search? All together, it's a bit much.

Comment: I am a bit confused by 'too broad' but I suppose if I were forced to ask one simple question it would be: How do you take the VB script in the referenced question/answer and give it the ability to handle wildcards in the keyword?  For example, can you change 'equals file.name' to 'like file.name'?

Comment: I'm suggesting it's too broad because it sounds like the question is actually three questions. 1 How to get user input (or how best to get user input) 2 how to search files on a computer using a wildcard 3 how to parse the results so that only the filename is returned. That being said, the question in your link is even more broad and it got an answer, so I guess it's not out of the question.

Comment: I took a shot at the wildcard portion of the question and also managed to pick off the "File Name instead of Full File Path" question too since it was a quickie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your second question "How do I modify the code in the link to search using a wildcard". The code in question is the Subroutine:

```
Sub FindFile(searchname, searchdir) ' Two parameters: file name, search directory
    On Error Resume Next ' Enable error handling so we don't crash out on access denied errors
    Dim file, folder, subfolder
    For Each file In fso.GetFolder(searchdir).Files ' Process each file (as a file object) in the search directory
        If LCase(searchname) = LCase(file.Name) Then ' See if file name matches. Using LCase to convert both to lowercase for case insensitivity.
            ReDim Preserve fileslist(UBound(fileslist) + 1) ' If match found then increase array size by 1
            fileslist(UBound(fileslist)) = file.Path ' Store the file path in newly added array entry
        End If
    Next
    ' Now the recursive bit. For any subfolders in current search directory, call FindFile again
    ' with (1) the same file name originally passed in as "searchname", and (2) a new search 
    ' directory of the subfolder's name. FindFile then starts again on this new directory: finds files, 
    ' adds matches to the fileslist array, then does the same on each subfolder found. This 
    ' is how it searches each subfolder (and subfolders of subfolders... etc) in a directory
    For Each subfolder In fso.GetFolder(searchdir).SubFolders
        FindFile searchname, subfolder.Path
    Next
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

The important bit here is the line `If LCase(searchname) = LCase(file.Name) Then`. We can change this to:

```
If instr(1,LCase(file.Name), LCase(searchname)) Then
```

Which will return true if the `searchname` is contained in the string `file.name`, which works as a wildcard type search.

The following line:

```
fileslist(UBound(fileslist)) = file.Path
```

Could be changed to:

```
fileslist(UBound(fileslist)) = file.Name
```

In order to just get the name instead of the path.